# Why do Z/7 have no cubic root of 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups, finite-fields

I was reading a textbook and came across the following line:

> Now we prove there is no cube root of 2 in $Z/7$. By noting that $(Z/7)^\times$ is cyclic of order 6, it will have only two third powers, which are ±1 by observation. Therefore by exclusion 2 can't be a cube in $Z/7$

I have two questions about this passage.

1. Why are we talking about a corresponding cyclic group when the point is to prove facts in Z/7?
2. Why does order 6 in a cyclic group imply only a two third power? Is there a formula of number of nth power based on the order of a cyclic group?

Comment: If $x^3=2$, then $x$ is a unit, since $2$ is a unit. So it suffices to consider the group of units of your ring.

Comment: Hint: squaring $\,x^3\equiv 2\,\Rightarrow\, x^6 \equiv 4\,$ vs. $\,x^6\equiv 1\,$ by little Fermat, by $\,x\not\equiv 0$

Comment: 2  3, 4, and 5  are not cubes  in your ring in wich the cubes are just 0, 1 and 6.

Comment: The reason to consider the cyclic group is that it is simpler to reason about a cyclic group. The cyclic group doesn't contain every element of $\mathbb{Z}/7$, but the only element that is being left out that way is $0$. And since $0$ obviously isn't the cube root of $2$, that doesn't invalidate the conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that since $x^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ for all $x$ not divisible by $7$, for any nonzero cube $y$ we have that
$$y^2\equiv 1\pmod{7}$$
The only two solutions to this equation are $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Answers:

1. In order to understand the *ring* $\Bbb Z_7$, we are examining the groups that the units form under multiplication, which is given by $(\Bbb Z_7)^\times$.  This group is a cyclic group of order $6$.
2. In any group $G$ of order $n$ (i.e of $n$ elements) with identity $e$, $g^n = e$ for any $g \in G$.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is cyclic of order $n$ and $d\mid n$ then multiplication by $d$ is a group endomorphism with kernel of size $d$ and image of size $\frac nd$. Here, taking third power in the (multiplicative) cyclic group of nonzero elements of $\mathbb Z/7$ has image size $\frac 63=2$. By exhibiting two elements of this image we then finally know that no other element is in the image (where "is in the image" means "has a cube root")

Answer (score 3):

1. Since $7$ is prime, the cyclic group $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ consists of all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ except $0$, which is not a cube root of $2$.
2. Suppose $a$ is a third power in $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$. This is to say that $a = x^3$ for some $x$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Since the order of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is $6$, it follows that $x^6 = 1$ and therefore $a^2 = x^6 = 1$. One then checks by brute force (or a little number theory `:)`) that the only two elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$ satisfying $a^2 = 1$ are $a = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

for what it's worth, reasoning is nice, but you can also just cube all seven elements and observe that you never get $2$